# Disable a block based on user agent

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to disable certain blocks to some user agents. The question may sound vague, but any hint will be very helpful.

I have this code and I think I have to modify something here.

```
final class Rand_Page_Model_Observer_HideBlocksObserver
{
    /**
     * Hide Header and Footer from cms page for "sg-mobile-app"
     * user-agent (handles event "controller_action_layout_load_before")
     */
    public function hideBlocks(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $layout Mage_Core_Model_Layout */
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $handles = $layout->getUpdate()->getHandles();

        $req = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        $userAgent = $req->getHeader('User-Agent') ?: null;
        $hideContainers = f\nullable('boolval', $req->getQuery('hide-containers'));
        if ($hideContainers === false) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->canExcludeHandle($handles) && ($userAgent === 'sg-mobile-app' || $hideContainers)) {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('hide_blocks');
        }
    }

    private function canExcludeHandle(array $handles): bool {
        $handlesToExclude = ['cms_page', 'sales_guest_form', 'sales_guest_view'];
        return f\any(c\inArray($handlesToExclude), $handles);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You think maybe it will be easier to detect in Javascript and hide content?

I've used this before

https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

Just a suggestion.  Might be easier than trying to do this within Magento backend code.

Although obviously users can spoof user-agent. So no approach will be flawless.